# Kotlin-Exposed's own example on their wiki does not work

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, h2, kotlin-exposed

This code is pulled directly off of the [Kotlin-Exposed Wiki](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/Getting-Started) yet does not work. Strange and frustrating that I cannot get it to work since I have an idea for a cool project which requires using a RDBMS. What am I missing? Is it broken?

```
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.StdOutSqlLogger
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.insert
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.transaction
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.selectAll

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Database.connect("jdbc:h2:mem:test", driver = "org.h2.Driver")

    transaction {
        logger.addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)

        val stPeteId = Cities.insert {
            it[name] = "St. Petersburg"
        } get Cities.id

        println("Cities: ${Cities.selectAll()}")
    }
}

// Table definition
object Cities : Table() {
    val id = integer("id").autoIncrement().primaryKey()
    val name = varchar("name", 50)
}
// Entity definition
data class City(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String
)
```

When run in Intellij, I recieve this error message:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "CITIES" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO CITIES (NAME) VALUES (?) [42102-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5552)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5529)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1062)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:417)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:321)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:293)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:258)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:578)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:519)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:1188)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.InsertStatement.prepared(InsertStatement.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.Statement.executeIn$exposed(Statement.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.exec(Transaction.kt:103)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.exec(Transaction.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.Statement.execute(Statement.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.QueriesKt.insert(Queries.kt:43)
    at MainKt$main$1.invoke(Main.kt:14)
    at MainKt$main$1.invoke(Main.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:55)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:11)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the create statement is missing from their example. The DAO example [on the project's GitHub page](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed#dao-sample) seems to have a few statements that the example you point to does not.

Try adding a create statement:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Database.connect("jdbc:h2:mem:test", driver = "org.h2.Driver")

    transaction {
        logger.addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)

        // ADD THIS - Create tables
        create (Cities)

        val stPeteId = Cities.insert {
            it[name] = "St. Petersburg"
        } get Cities.id

        println("Cities: ${Cities.selectAll()}")
    }
}
```

And if that works, I bet they would accept a PR for their documentation.